# Seaborn Catplot: Number of rows must be a positive integer, not 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I have dataframe which looks as follow:

```
df = 
crashYear   region  OBJECTID
0   2000    Auckland Region 12285
1   2000    Bay of Plenty Region    1336
2   2000    Canterbury Region   3563
3   2000    Gisborne Region 319
4   2000    Hawke's Bay Region  1236
5   2000    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1984
6   2000    Marlborough Region  272
7   2000    Nelson Region   288
8   2000    Northland Region    1015
9   2000    Otago Region    1553
10  2000    Southland Region    717
11  2000    Taranaki Region 761
12  2000    Tasman Region   296
13  2000    Waikato Region  2749
14  2000    Wellington Region   3197
15  2000    West Coast Region   294
16  2001    Auckland Region 13670
17  2001    Bay of Plenty Region    1741
18  2001    Canterbury Region   3884
19  2001    Gisborne Region 435
20  2001    Hawke's Bay Region  1318
21  2001    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   2038
22  2001    Marlborough Region  303
23  2001    Nelson Region   328
24  2001    Northland Region    1120
25  2001    Otago Region    1971
26  2001    Southland Region    928
27  2001    Taranaki Region 804
28  2001    Tasman Region   295
29  2001    Waikato Region  3638
30  2001    Wellington Region   3225
31  2001    West Coast Region   281
32  2002    Auckland Region 14811
33  2002    Bay of Plenty Region    1951
34  2002    Canterbury Region   3670
35  2002    Gisborne Region 450
36  2002    Hawke's Bay Region  1435
37  2002    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   2237
38  2002    Marlborough Region  387
39  2002    Nelson Region   391
40  2002    Northland Region    1236
41  2002    Otago Region    2257
42  2002    Southland Region    969
43  2002    Taranaki Region 839
44  2002    Tasman Region   321
45  2002    Waikato Region  3465
46  2002    Wellington Region   3218
47  2002    West Coast Region   270
48  2003    Auckland Region 14445
49  2003    Bay of Plenty Region    2267
50  2003    Canterbury Region   3548
51  2003    Gisborne Region 416
52  2003    Hawke's Bay Region  1565
53  2003    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   2067
54  2003    Marlborough Region  345
55  2003    Nelson Region   409
56  2003    Northland Region    1552
57  2003    Otago Region    2102
58  2003    Southland Region    950
59  2003    Taranaki Region 784
60  2003    Tasman Region   385
61  2003    Waikato Region  3652
62  2003    Wellington Region   3063
63  2003    West Coast Region   273
64  2004    Auckland Region 13426
65  2004    Bay of Plenty Region    2143
66  2004    Canterbury Region   3322
67  2004    Gisborne Region 450
68  2004    Hawke's Bay Region  1643
69  2004    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1997
70  2004    Marlborough Region  378
71  2004    Nelson Region   427
72  2004    Northland Region    1540
73  2004    Otago Region    2190
74  2004    Southland Region    887
75  2004    Taranaki Region 755
76  2004    Tasman Region   349
77  2004    Waikato Region  3678
78  2004    Wellington Region   3374
79  2004    West Coast Region   350
80  2005    Auckland Region 13588
81  2005    Bay of Plenty Region    2281
82  2005    Canterbury Region   3722
83  2005    Gisborne Region 480
84  2005    Hawke's Bay Region  1730
85  2005    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   2087
86  2005    Marlborough Region  397
87  2005    Nelson Region   352
88  2005    Northland Region    1450
89  2005    Otago Region    2133
90  2005    Southland Region    955
91  2005    Taranaki Region 810
92  2005    Tasman Region   289
93  2005    Waikato Region  4170
94  2005    Wellington Region   3455
95  2005    West Coast Region   311
96  2006    Auckland Region 13763
97  2006    Bay of Plenty Region    2296
98  2006    Canterbury Region   4210
99  2006    Gisborne Region 446
100 2006    Hawke's Bay Region  1611
101 2006    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   2047
102 2006    Marlborough Region  412
103 2006    Nelson Region   410
104 2006    Northland Region    1543
105 2006    Otago Region    2145
106 2006    Southland Region    971
107 2006    Taranaki Region 841
108 2006    Tasman Region   310
109 2006    Waikato Region  4307
110 2006    Wellington Region   4037
111 2006    West Coast Region   321
112 2007    Auckland Region 13887
113 2007    Bay of Plenty Region    2314
114 2007    Canterbury Region   4542
115 2007    Gisborne Region 423
116 2007    Hawke's Bay Region  1844
117 2007    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1972
118 2007    Marlborough Region  419
119 2007    Nelson Region   408
120 2007    Northland Region    1630
121 2007    Otago Region    2234
122 2007    Southland Region    978
123 2007    Taranaki Region 995
124 2007    Tasman Region   374
125 2007    Waikato Region  4282
126 2007    Wellington Region   4881
127 2007    West Coast Region   339
128 2008    Auckland Region 13548
129 2008    Bay of Plenty Region    2096
130 2008    Canterbury Region   4180
131 2008    Gisborne Region 503
132 2008    Hawke's Bay Region  1554
133 2008    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1901
134 2008    Marlborough Region  387
135 2008    Nelson Region   417
136 2008    Northland Region    1560
137 2008    Otago Region    2195
138 2008    Southland Region    1020
139 2008    Taranaki Region 965
140 2008    Tasman Region   349
141 2008    Waikato Region  3909
142 2008    Wellington Region   4488
143 2008    West Coast Region   320
144 2009    Auckland Region 12866
145 2009    Bay of Plenty Region    2208
146 2009    Canterbury Region   3937
147 2009    Gisborne Region 519
148 2009    Hawke's Bay Region  1562
149 2009    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1806
150 2009    Marlborough Region  376
151 2009    Nelson Region   422
152 2009    Northland Region    1550
153 2009    Otago Region    2204
154 2009    Southland Region    1069
155 2009    Taranaki Region 923
156 2009    Tasman Region   338
157 2009    Waikato Region  3826
158 2009    Wellington Region   4114
159 2009    West Coast Region   377
160 2010    Auckland Region 12753
161 2010    Bay of Plenty Region    2081
162 2010    Canterbury Region   3471
163 2010    Gisborne Region 506
164 2010    Hawke's Bay Region  1502
165 2010    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   2027
166 2010    Marlborough Region  354
167 2010    Nelson Region   394
168 2010    Northland Region    1441
169 2010    Otago Region    2046
170 2010    Southland Region    999
171 2010    Taranaki Region 856
172 2010    Tasman Region   297
173 2010    Waikato Region  3770
174 2010    Wellington Region   3827
175 2010    West Coast Region   357
176 2011    Auckland Region 11258
177 2011    Bay of Plenty Region    1942
178 2011    Canterbury Region   3266
179 2011    Gisborne Region 394
180 2011    Hawke's Bay Region  1249
181 2011    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1917
182 2011    Marlborough Region  320
183 2011    Nelson Region   297
184 2011    Northland Region    1224
185 2011    Otago Region    1843
186 2011    Southland Region    816
187 2011    Taranaki Region 805
188 2011    Tasman Region   310
189 2011    Waikato Region  3548
190 2011    Wellington Region   2852
191 2011    West Coast Region   271
192 2012    Auckland Region 10865
193 2012    Bay of Plenty Region    1630
194 2012    Canterbury Region   3260
195 2012    Gisborne Region 347
196 2012    Hawke's Bay Region  1029
197 2012    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1717
198 2012    Marlborough Region  293
199 2012    Nelson Region   295
200 2012    Northland Region    1216
201 2012    Otago Region    1689
202 2012    Southland Region    783
203 2012    Taranaki Region 716
204 2012    Tasman Region   263
205 2012    Waikato Region  3226
206 2012    Wellington Region   2731
207 2012    West Coast Region   264
208 2013    Auckland Region 10686
209 2013    Bay of Plenty Region    1633
210 2013    Canterbury Region   3306
211 2013    Gisborne Region 363
212 2013    Hawke's Bay Region  1045
213 2013    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1644
214 2013    Marlborough Region  266
215 2013    Nelson Region   288
216 2013    Northland Region    1193
217 2013    Otago Region    1609
218 2013    Southland Region    756
219 2013    Taranaki Region 670
220 2013    Tasman Region   290
221 2013    Waikato Region  3041
222 2013    Wellington Region   2968
223 2013    West Coast Region   256
224 2014    Auckland Region 10640
225 2014    Bay of Plenty Region    1564
226 2014    Canterbury Region   3350
227 2014    Gisborne Region 295
228 2014    Hawke's Bay Region  998
229 2014    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1671
230 2014    Marlborough Region  282
231 2014    Nelson Region   273
232 2014    Northland Region    1265
233 2014    Otago Region    1570
234 2014    Southland Region    817
235 2014    Taranaki Region 602
236 2014    Tasman Region   213
237 2014    Waikato Region  3134
238 2014    Wellington Region   2745
239 2014    West Coast Region   264
240 2015    Auckland Region 11442
241 2015    Bay of Plenty Region    1799
242 2015    Canterbury Region   3255
243 2015    Gisborne Region 284
244 2015    Hawke's Bay Region  1002
245 2015    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1828
246 2015    Marlborough Region  317
247 2015    Nelson Region   281
248 2015    Northland Region    1366
249 2015    Otago Region    1855
250 2015    Southland Region    861
251 2015    Taranaki Region 675
252 2015    Tasman Region   259
253 2015    Waikato Region  3549
254 2015    Wellington Region   2919
255 2015    West Coast Region   311
256 2016    Auckland Region 13308
257 2016    Bay of Plenty Region    2267
258 2016    Canterbury Region   3624
259 2016    Gisborne Region 362
260 2016    Hawke's Bay Region  1340
261 2016    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   1900
262 2016    Marlborough Region  417
263 2016    Nelson Region   348
264 2016    Northland Region    1501
265 2016    Otago Region    2018
266 2016    Southland Region    941
267 2016    Taranaki Region 742
268 2016    Tasman Region   359
269 2016    Waikato Region  3989
270 2016    Wellington Region   3617
271 2016    West Coast Region   369
272 2017    Auckland Region 13786
273 2017    Bay of Plenty Region    2296
274 2017    Canterbury Region   3660
275 2017    Gisborne Region 387
276 2017    Hawke's Bay Region  1388
277 2017    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   2188
278 2017    Marlborough Region  431
279 2017    Nelson Region   350
280 2017    Northland Region    1670
281 2017    Otago Region    1927
282 2017    Southland Region    814
283 2017    Taranaki Region 779
284 2017    Tasman Region   449
285 2017    Waikato Region  4688
286 2017    Wellington Region   3957
287 2017    West Coast Region   409
288 2018    Auckland Region 12631
289 2018    Bay of Plenty Region    2366
290 2018    Canterbury Region   3551
291 2018    Gisborne Region 485
292 2018    Hawke's Bay Region  1478
293 2018    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   2210
294 2018    Marlborough Region  442
295 2018    Nelson Region   366
296 2018    Northland Region    1841
297 2018    Otago Region    1979
298 2018    Southland Region    821
299 2018    Taranaki Region 839
300 2018    Tasman Region   390
301 2018    Waikato Region  4692
302 2018    Wellington Region   3835
303 2018    West Coast Region   376
304 2019    Auckland Region 11786
305 2019    Bay of Plenty Region    2445
306 2019    Canterbury Region   3275
307 2019    Gisborne Region 466
308 2019    Hawke's Bay Region  1465
309 2019    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   2208
310 2019    Marlborough Region  450
311 2019    Nelson Region   379
312 2019    Northland Region    1670
313 2019    Otago Region    2039
314 2019    Southland Region    864
315 2019    Taranaki Region 844
316 2019    Tasman Region   375
317 2019    Waikato Region  4477
318 2019    Wellington Region   3655
319 2019    West Coast Region   380
320 2020    Auckland Region 9337
321 2020    Bay of Plenty Region    2037
322 2020    Canterbury Region   3020
323 2020    Gisborne Region 482
324 2020    Hawke's Bay Region  1376
325 2020    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   2065
326 2020    Marlborough Region  341
327 2020    Nelson Region   318
328 2020    Northland Region    1477
329 2020    Otago Region    1654
330 2020    Southland Region    751
331 2020    Taranaki Region 795
332 2020    Tasman Region   331
333 2020    Waikato Region  3746
334 2020    Wellington Region   3042
335 2020    West Coast Region   291
336 2021    Auckland Region 1461
337 2021    Bay of Plenty Region    365
338 2021    Canterbury Region   511
339 2021    Gisborne Region 66
340 2021    Hawke's Bay Region  216
341 2021    Manawatū-Whanganui Region   362
342 2021    Marlborough Region  44
343 2021    Nelson Region   54
344 2021    Northland Region    239
345 2021    Otago Region    245
346 2021    Southland Region    120
347 2021    Taranaki Region 118
348 2021    Tasman Region   62
349 2021    Waikato Region  663
350 2021    Wellington Region   447
351 2021    West Coast Region   47
```

I want to draw barplot using seaborn catplot and want to display the regional data in 4 x 4 matrix. Following is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.catplot(data=df,kind='bar',y='OBJECTID',x='crashYear',col_wrap=4)
```

When I ran the above code, it thows me following error:

```
ValueError: Number of rows must be a positive integer, not 0
```

I am not sure where I made the mistake. Could anyone help me in fixing the issue?

Comment: Maybe you also need `col='region'`? Otherwise there would only be one subplot and `col_wrap` wouldn't be used. Are you using the latest seaborn 0.11.2?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `col='region'` parameter:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.catplot(data=df, kind='bar', y='OBJECTID', x='crashYear', col='region', col_wrap=4)
```

output:

[image: catplot]